# how to combine two different arrays to associative array?

Tags: php

I have two arrays

```
1. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 151 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 152 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 148 ) ) 

2. Array ( [0] => 2019-03-11 [1] => 2019-03-08 [2] => 2019-03-09 )
```

How can I get Array like this

```
array(
    151 => 2019-03-11,
    152 => 2019-03-08,
    148 => 2019-03-09
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the sub array elements from `$array1` and use them as the keys and `$array2` values as the values:

```
$result = array_combine(array_column($array1, 0), $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, right after I asked a question, I was able to solve it this way.

```
$a= call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);

$c = array_combine($a, $b);
```